# How to use Gmail API without OAuth consent screen?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'd like to use Gmail API to automatically reply on some emails.
The app works only by authorizing by Google OAuth consent screen.
The problem is that the time of the token is limited, and I need the program to work by itself without user involvement.
Is there are way to use service account (but need to answer emails with the main email address)? Or  somehow make the unlimited token?

I'm tried to use service account

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
threads = service.users().threads().list(userId='me', q='is:unread').execute().get('threads', [])
print(threads)
```

but it returned 401 Error error:

```
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using service account as a workaround for Consent Screen:

Answering your whole post. 0Auth Token limited is as is and cannot be modified or there is no direct work around with that. Moreover your approach using a Service Account is a viable option for you. Your issue is most likely because of the Domain Wide Delegation.

## Solution:

Set up your Domain Wide Delegation.

- In the Admin console, go to **Menu** and then **Security** and then **Access and data control** and then **API controls**.
- Click Manage Domain Wide Delegation. Click Add new and enter your service account client ID.

> You can find the ID (also known as the Unique ID) in the JSON file that you downloaded when you created the service account or in Google Cloud (click IAM & Admin and thenService accounts and then the name of your service account).

- Enter the client ID of the service account or OAuth2 client ID of the app. (Typically, the ID is provided by the developer. If you're the owner of the service account, you can look up the ID.)

You can read more about this in this [article.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client)

You need additional parameters on your method.

You have to change this part:

```
 creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

To this:

```
 creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, subject = "emailoftheaccountyoumimic@example.com")
```

### References:

[Domain Wide Delegation](https://%20%5B1%5D:%20https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client)

[Service Accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en&sjid=8100791248734984412-AP)

> For additional reference. I happen to stumble upon a non official
> [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpmWlHRVn9c&list=PL3JVwFmb_BnSHlyy3gItOar_Y8w45mbJx&index=8)
> that I think might help you.