# Is there any way to read emails from Gmail without using domain-wide delegation and OAuth consent screen?

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to parse and read emails from Gmail. The domain-wide delegation is not suitable for my requirements and OAuth consent screen also

For now, I created an app engine service that receives incoming emails, and I can parse them. However, it is not as flexible as using Gmail API.

Also, I did this option, but the solution to using the domain-wide delegation is not suitable
[How to use Gmail API without OAuth consent screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77055812/how-to-use-gmail-api-without-oauth-consent-screen)